# Updating property values in one list with a property value average of matching items in another list

Tags: c#, linq, extension-methods

I have two Lists and need to update a property value of all the items in the 1st list with a property value average of all the matching items in another list.

```
class transaction
{
  public string orderId;
  public string parentOrderId;
  public int quantity;
  public decimal marketPrice;
  public decimal fillPrice;
}

List<transaction> makerTransactions = new List<transaction>()
{
  new transaction(){
                     orderId = "1",
                     parentOrderId = "1",
                     quantity = 100,
                     marketPrice = 75.87M,
                     fillPrice = 75.87M
                   }
};

List<transaction> takerTransactions = new List<transaction>()
{
  new transaction(){
                     orderId = "2",
                     parentOrderId = "1",
                     quantity = 50,
                     marketPrice = 75.97M,
                     fillPrice = 75.97M
                    },
  new transaction(){
                     orderId = "3",
                     parentOrderId = "1",
                     quantity = 50,
                     marketPrice = 75.85M,
                     fillPrice = 75.85M
                    }
};
```

Trying to make this work with LINQ extension methods but cant figure out the correct way.

```
makerTransactions.All(mt => mt.fillPrice = takerTransactions
                 .Where(tt => tt.parentOrderId == mt.orderId)
                 .Average(ta => ta.fillPrice));
```

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
  makerTransactions.ForEach(mt => mt.fillPrice = takerTransactions
     .Where(tt => tt.parentOrderId == mt.orderId)
     .Average(ta => ta.fillPrice));
```

All is an extension method. It tells you if all the elements in a collection match a certain condition and, apparently, it's not what you need.

To make it more efficient, first create a dictionary and use that to take the averages from:

```
var priceDictionary = takerTransactions
     .GroupBy(tt => tt.parentOrderId)
     .ToDictionary(grp => gr.Key, grp => grp.Average(ta => ta.fillPrice));

makerTransactions.ForEach(mt => mt.fillPrice = priceDictionary[mt.orderId]);
```

Comment: I would create a dictionary of `orderId` (key) and `average` (value) first (using a LINQ statement and `ToDictionary`). It's quite expensive to calculate the average for each iteration.

Comment: @GertArnold Could you please explain your suggestion in some more detail? I still need to iterate all the items in the first list, searching for matching records in the second list and averaging the matches.